# Firestore Security Rules, Regex, how to avoid special chracters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

I`m looking at this right now and feel kinda hard to understand and tricky

I just want to set regex "only allows lower alphabet and numbers and  - _ * # .  these five special characters.

how could I acheive that ? thanks

Comment: Are you using the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore? (They are two different services with different security rules syntax)

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec Hi I use "Cloud Firestore"

Answer (score 3):

If you use **Cloud Firestore** you should declare your regular expressions according to [Google RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), see the doc about the [`matches()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) method.

The link you mention in your question is about the Realtime Database Security rules. The Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two different NoSQL Database services with different security rules syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks. I just see that syntaxs that you linked but still huge confused. I just want to set regex "only allows lower alphabet and numbers and - _ * # . these five special characters. could you please help me please

Comment: Something like this should work: `allow write: if request.resource.data.message.matches('[a-z0-9-_\*#]+')`. If you're having a hard time making that work, edit your question to show what you tried already.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thanks Frank but I got error this Line 18: Missing a closing '; Line 18: mismatched input ']' expecting {'--', '++', '{', '[', '(', '-', '!', '/', 'false', 'null', 'true', PATH_SEGMENT, IDENTIFIER, NUM_INT, NUM_FLOAT, UNPAIRED_DOUBLE_QUOTE, UNPAIRED_SINGLE_QUOTE, STRING, BYTES}; Line 19: Missing a closing '; Line 19: missing ')' at '}'